# MacBook keeps switching off bluetooth

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth

Any ideas why Bluetooth keeps switching off on its own?

I've noticed it happens when there are no devices connected or when in sleep.

```
Device: MacBook Pro, M1 Max, 2021. 14-inch
Version: MacOS 13.3.1 (22E261)
```

[image: Bluetooth switched off]

Comment: Assuming this is just “off” and not “disabled” or “not found” and you can re-enable by simply turning back on, it would appear to be a bug.  When your Mac goes to sleep, it turns off BT.  When you wake, it’s supposed to turn back on.  This is something you should contact Apple Support about and open a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by an MDM application (Kandji in this case). It was pre-installed in my work laptop.

Comment: You should have said that you had an MDM solution installed.

Comment: @Razär Did you find a way to solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @GabrielMochi, yes, it was caused by some MDM software. Are you having this problem on a work computer? If so, that might be the cause.